# Is there a way to preview User's time sheet in Project Web App?

Tags: ms-project

There was an option for an admin to preview the time sheet for a user in Project Web App (PWA). Admins can navigate to time sheets and preview only own time sheets. Is there a way to somehow preview a user's time sheet using an admin account?

We are using PWA and single entry mode for time sheet and task.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Resource Center.
2. Select the resource (tick the checkbox) and select 'Resource Assignments'.
3. Select 'Timephased' view and period to display the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this article; https://projectassistants.com/2019/03/12/progress-tracking-using-project-web-app-timesheet-page-and-task-time-approval/
It explains with steps and screenshots how to navigate PWA I think it might help you better.